# Why is it bad practice to use implicit id references in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen and avoided code like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" onClick="alert('hi!');">Div</div>
<script>
    myDiv.click();  // <-- this bit seems wrong
</script>
```

It just seems wrong to me that I should refer to the node by it's id alone without explicitly assigning it to a variable first.  Like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

Is there a good reason why we shouldn't use code like in the first example or am I just superstitious?

Comment: It's just a bad practise. It doesn't even need to be "unsafe"

Comment: Why is it bad practice?

Comment: Related: [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572)

Comment: Out the top of my head, I'd say: Global variables | Risks of collisions | Shadowing | Quirks Mode | Explicit is better than implicit

Comment: [This may help](http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom#implicit-id-valued-variables)

Comment: Thanks Bergi and Pete.  If one of you wants the spoils answer my question and I'll give you the accepted answer kudos.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi and Pete for links to useful information on this topic.

From these I have gleaned there are few main reasons why this is bad practice:

1. It's not supported in all browsers (although with html5 adopting implicit references this approach this may not be an issue going forward).
2. Namespace collision - the reference is put as a property on this window object.  If a window property with a name the same as the id exists it may not be assigned.
3. Due to point 2, your code could break unexpectedly if a browser introduces a property with the same name as one of your ids.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to use the identifiers from the page without specifying where they come from.

The identifiers are "magically" created as properties in the document object. If you use those, it's not clearly apperent how they got there in the first place. If you rename the element, the same Javascript code now creates a global variable instead, and it's hard to see by looking at the code what it was supposed to do, and why it's not working any more.

Also there is a risk for conflicts. If you create a global variable with the same name as the element id, then it will shadow the element and you can no longer reach it.

By using `getElementById` the code clearly says that there should be an element with that id in the page, and it also only looks for an element so the risk for naming conflicts is less.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, it is a bad practice since the maintenance of such code will be very difficult, consider that the `script` is not located next to the element or even not in the same file.

Moreover, using `id`s in general is not recommended when your HTML page/app grows. The `id` attribute must remains unique and you may find it hard to follow it

Comment: Who on earth is recommending not to use IDs in general?

Comment: using `id` when having 'many-pages' app, multiple events, data-binding and auto-generating template mechanism, you would rather avoid using an `id` attribute. I also mentioned that *it is not recommended* when the app grows, as general comment